# How to request page content by clicking a div with jQuery mobile?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mobile, jquery-mobile

I am trying to fetch data form a callback page (php) and load it into a html div with **jQuery mobile**. This should happen if a user clicks on another div.

What I actually got is

```
$.('#home-button').bind('vclick', function( e ) {
    $.get('homeCallback.php',function(data){
        $('#displayContent').append(data).trigger('create');
    },'html');
});
```

Where `#home-button` is the div that should trigger the event and `#displayContent` the div where the content should be put in.
The request should be able to pass some parameters, too. Like `homeCallback.php?param=1` but it could also use the post method.
The callback does not have to be html only, it could also be possible that the callback php script provides JSON data or anything.

I am not a JS crack so I have problems solving this issue. Thanks for your help!

**Edit:**
So I found a solution on my own:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup ({
        cache: false
    });

    var ajaxLoader = '<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="loading.." />'; 
    var loadUrl = "homeCallback.php";  

    $('#home-button1').click(function(){
        $('#displayContent').toggle('fast', function() {
            $(this).html(ajaxLoader);
            $(this).toggle('fast', function() {
                $.get(loadUrl + '?option1',function(data){
                    $('#displayContent').html(data);
                },'html');                  
            });
        });
    });

    $('#home-button2').click(function(){
        $('#displayContent').toggle('fast', function() {
            $(this).html(ajaxLoader);
            $(this).toggle('fast', function() {
                $.get(loadUrl + '?option2',function(data){
                    $('#displayContent').html(data);
                },'html');                  
            });
        });
    });
});
```

And this is what `homeCallback.php` simply does..

```
<?php
if( isset($_GET["option1"] ))
    echo "option1";
if( isset($_GET["option2"] ))
    echo "option2";
```

So far.

Comment: That's fine, but I'd consider using the appropriate jQM page event, rather than `$(document).ready`, especially if you plan on adding pages to your application.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.('#home-button').bind('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "homeCallback.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: ({param: 1, param2: 2}),
        success: function(html){
            $("#displayContent").html(html);
        }
    });
});
```